# Left Italy before getting my residency permit

Tags: legal

I traveled to Italy at the end of October with a tourist visa, which expired on November 8th. I applied for my first residency permit on November 9th and scheduled a fingerprint appointment for September 2024. However, this was inconvenient for me as I had to return to my home country to complete my thesis. Despite exploring various solutions, I couldn't find a suitable option. Consequently, I decided to leave Italy in January 2024 without a residency permit and with an expired visa. Fortunately, everything went smoothly at the airport as I had the postal receipt for my permit application. My concern now is whether this might pose any future issues, as I plan to apply for a German national visa (16d)

Comment: This should be on expats SE in my opinion

Comment: Which kind of visa? I certainly see that, if you ask for a tourist visa, German authorities might believe that you want to stay in the country regardless of visa limits...

Comment: National visa 16d

Comment: Then include that information into your question. [§16d - Measures regarding the recognition of foreign professional qualifications](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0306)